# change of tense in indirectquestion after 'the question was'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A boy was bothered about the disappearance of clouds.  What do we say :
The question that bothered the boy was where the clouds went.
                                         or
The question that bothered the boy was where had the clouds gone.

Comment: What direct speech question did the boy ask? "Where do the clouds go?" → *... was where the clouds went.* "Where have the clouds gone?" → *... was where the clouds had gone.*

Answer (score 1):

> The question that kept bothering the boy was where the clouds had gone.

Or:

> The question bothering the boy was what had happened to the clouds.

A bit of clarification might be in order. Here goes:

"The question" here doesn't have to be an inquiry per se. As in, ***To be or not to be, that is the question***.

Answer (score 0):

The question of where clouds go bothered the boy.

Sounds superior to your options and avoids passive voice.

Comment: Neither of the options being asked about uses the passive voice.  The question uses the passive voice only in describing situation described by the examples.

Comment: You're right, I kneejerked over the 'was'.

Comment: Hi, user156476. Welcome to EL&U. We are not sure whether we have to use **went** instead of **go**. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.